# How to set width of paper-textarea in Polymer 1.0?

Tags: css, css-selectors, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

Does anybody knows how to set the width of a `paper-textarea`? Using CSS selectors in Polymer 1.0 style tags seems **not** to work at all. The `paper-textarea` element is composed with `paper-input-container`. So I tried to do the following:

```
<style>
  paper-textarea + paper-input-container {
    min-width: 324px;
    width: 324px;
    margin-right: 24px;
  }
  paper-textarea > paper-input-container {
    min-width: 324px;
    width: 324px;
    margin-right: 24px;
  }
  paper-textarea paper-input-container {
    min-width: 324px;
    width: 324px;
    margin-right: 24px;
  }
</style>
```

Neither of the CSS selectors above worked in my custom element.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
    :root {
        --paper-input-container: {
            min-width: 324px;
            width: 324px;
            margin-right: 24px;
        };
    }
</style>
```

Will do the trick. It will style every polymer element that makes use of a paper-input-container (like paper-textarea) to the above width and margin.